# How to access the xpath I defined in my page model using the Capybara::Node::Element Query

Tags: ruby

Trying to access the xpath using the element-
I am trying to access the xpath in the locator attribute of a Capybara::Node::Element, but it says undefined method 'query'.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  I'd also advise reading [mcve].  Good luck!

Comment: Gokul, please include capybara tag as well when you ask questions related to capybara.

Answer (score 0):

If you show Your code and add a few suggestions of what You do and what you want to get, people will be able to understand and help You.

Most likely there are several problems:

- You are not using xpath correctly
- You've found the xpath